# Probability problem of digging a tunnel from two sides

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

A tunnel of length 170 m will be drilled from two sides. From experience we know that what is managed in different days can be understood as a stochastic variable with expected value 5.0 meters and standard deviation 1.2 meters.

Find out with a suitable approximation the probability that the tunnel takes more than 18 days to be completed.

I know the CLT and what it means but I get confused with the fact that we are supposed to calculate days and we are given meters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call $X_i$ the distance drilled by team $X$ on day $i$, and $Y_i$ the distance drilled by team $Y$

You need to find the probability that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{18} (X_i+Y_i) < 170$$

Now you can make your approximations ( first, $X_i \sim Y_i$ and the random variables are independant and identically distribued), so it's

$$\sum_{i=1}^{36} X_i < 170$$

Then you can use a normal approximation for this sum

Comment: shouldn't the inequality be the other way around?

Comment: @Mathguy007 : Oh yes ! I calculated the probability that the tunnel was *completed* in 18 days (or less) ;) Corrected

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just have one question. Could it be done another way, for instance, by converting everything into time. Because the way I thought of this problem at first was P(T<18) where T is a s.v. of the time it takes to complete the tunnel

Comment: @Mathguy007 : You can indeed see it like that, but $T$ is not easy to calculate